# Inactive User's records disappear from Salesforce reports

Tags: reporting

We have a leads report which shows the leads+owners of those leads.

For some reason we are not seeing leads in the report whose owner is inactive (ex-user).

Can some one tell me whether this is the expected behavior and if there is any workaround ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a quick test where I created a user in my dev org, had that user create a lead. Ran the report then deactivated the user and ran the report a 2nd time. The lead shows up on both reports. Double check your criteria against the records they owned it might be something else.
[image: When Active]
[image: After Deactivated]

Comment: Tx Jenny...I searched for a similar behavior from other posts online and found none ..so I assumed there must be something wrong with the report or something

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom report type, this is expected behavior (apparently). I was unaware this until recently as well. Inactive users' records WILL show up in standard SF reports but NOT custom report types. Un.Be.Lievable.